# Avoid duplicate partition in datalake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I write parquet file Im passing one of the column value as partition by but when the dataframe is empty it doesnt create the partition (it is expected) and does nothing. To overcome this if I pass

```
df.partitionOf("department=One").write(df)
```

and when the dataframe is NOT empty it creates two level of partition

```
location/department=One/department=One
```

Is there any way to skip one if the partition already exists to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Hi!
1 674 days later and we are facing a similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What is the path you are passing while writing dataframe? I didn't find partitionOf function for spark dataframe.

I think this should work for your case

`df.write.mode("append").partitionBy("department").parquet("location/")`

If you don't want to append data for the partitions which are already there find the partitons key from existing parquet and drop data with those partition keys and write remaining data in append mode.

scala code:

```
val dfi=spark.read.parquet(pathPrefix+finalFile).select(col("department"))
val finalDf = df.join(dfi, df.col("department") == dfi.col("department"), "left_outer")
                 .where(dfi.col("department").isNull())
                 .select(dfl.columns.map(col):_*)
finalDf.write.mode("append").partitionBy("department").parquet("location/")
```

You can optimize first step (creating dfi ) by finding partition keys from your Dataframe and  keeping only those partition keys for which path exists.